# Notification for keyboard fires also notification for defaults

Tags: iphone, ios4, notifications

I have this code in my ViewController:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear :(BOOL)animated {
     // register for keyboard notifications
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:) 
           name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:) 
           name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:self.view.window];

     // register for defaults change notification
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(defaultsChanged:)      
           name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification object:nil];
 }

 -(void) viewWillDisappear :(BOOL)animated {
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
 }
```

The problem is that when the keyboard appears, method defaultsChanged also is fired.

When keyboard appears, this is the sequence of calls (extract from the log):

```
start defaultsChanged 
end   defaultsChanged
start textFieldDidBeginEdit
end   textFieldDidBeginEdit
start keyboardWasShown
end   keyboardWasShown
```

I do not know what can be. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why do you call `[super dealloc]` in `viewWillDisappear :` method? You should call it in `- (void)dealloc` method

Comment: Oops, OK. I remove it. Obviously my problem persist.

Comment: BTW, you can remove all 3 of those notifications in one method call, no need to list them all.  `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the defaults really did change as a side effect of keyboard being shown?  Why don't you print out the defaults before and after and see if anything changed?  Here is some code to print NSUserDefaults with NSLog:

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary* defaultsDict = [defaults dictionaryRepresentation];
NSLog(@"defaults = %@", defaultsDict);
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. My personal default are the same, before and after. But now I see for the first time that defaults (as printed by you code) include other values (AppleLanguages, AppleLocale, NSInterfaceStyle, NSLanguages). This is before keyboard opens. After, includes all this, plus about 50 other items. All have the prefix WebKit and the first are:

Comment: WebKitAcceleratedCompositingEnabled = 1;
     WebKitAllowAnimatedImageLoopingPreferenceKey = 1;
     WebKitAllowAnimatedImagesPreferenceKey = 1;
     WebKitAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = 1;
     WebKitAllowMultiElementImplicitFormSubmissionPreferenceKey = 0;
     WebKitAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = 1;

Comment: I'm not familiar with WebKit, apparantly is stores some settings in the standardUserDefaults.